# pull content from the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

it is such that I have to make my first such real issues.

This is how I would like to pull something out of the database, that is, that as of 2-1-2015 to 2-28-2015 d must check some things out from the database. in the database I set date.

it means that it should just pull out from the månede one is just.

```
AND TransactionDate > DATEADD("dd", -30, GETDATE())
```

I've tried this, but it is not so really what I want but nothing like in the still, it just has to be such that it pulls out from the månede as one has come to / are in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what your question is, but I think it is something to the effect of "find all transactions that occurred this month". If this is correct, then you need to find the start date and end date of the current month and find the transactions between those values.

```
declare @start date = DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) * -1) + 1, GETDATE())
declare @end date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @start))

SELECT [your select here] FROM [your table here] WHERE [your where here] AND TransactionDate BETWEEN @start AND @end
```